# ssl connection using python 2.7.13 requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I tried to use python requests package to connect over SSL and i used below code.

```
resp = requests.get(addr , auth=HttpNtlmAuth(userFile[unum],passFile[pnum]) , headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.01 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'} , verify = False)
```

but every time i got below error.

```
("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)
```

UPDATE 1:

I dump host certificate and save that to c.cert and used below code.

```
resp = requests.get(addr , auth=HttpNtlmAuth(userFile[unum],passFile[pnum]) , headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.01 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'} , cert = '/home/user/Desktop/c.cert' , verify = '/home/user/Desktop/c.cert')
```

and new error.

```
[('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]
```

UPDATE 2 :

Here is what Burp Suite captured.

(First , session creation):

```
GET /PATH HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCQCTCTCQ=EPEHGDDAKOINODAJJKCELEOK
DNT: 1
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

(Second , when use credentials):

```
GET /PATH HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCQCTCTCQ=EPEHGDDAKOINODAJJKCELEOK
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
Connection: close
```

(Third , credentials was wrong)

```
GET /PATH HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCQCTCTCQ=EPEHGDDAKOINODAJJKCELEOK
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAGAAAACIAIgAeAAAAAAAAABAAAAACgAKAEAAAAAWABYASgAAAAAAAAAAAAAABYIIAGEAZABtAGkAbgBXAE8AUgBLAFMAVABBAFQASQBPAE4Ao8+kG6lMZcLmQys5IUkpayq+W1VFZPkjUQjxBhzugt88vU6RR3wahQEBAAAAAAAAgPonWPz30gGr58MfeUgvgQAAAAACABIAVwBFAEIAUwBFAFIAVgBFAFIAAQASAFcARQBCAFMARQBSAFYARQBSAAQAEgBXAEUAQgBTAEUAUgBWAEUAUgADABIAVwBFAEIAUwBFAFIAVgBFAFIAAAAAAA==
Connection: close
```

when using URL without HTTPS it gives me page with below custom error

**Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)**

Comment: The server closed the connection because it does not like what you've send. There can be many many reasons for this, like missing client certificate, incompatible ciphers or TLS protocol version ... . Please make sure that the connection works when using a different client like a browser and make sure that you have provided the same information as needed by the browser (like client certificate) to your script. Make also sure that you are using a recent version of OpenSSL, i.e. at least 1.0.1 since only this supports TLS 1.2. Check ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION for this.

Comment: openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0f-3). and when i use browser to connect, it works

Comment: Then I recommend to  make a packet capture of both the successful connection between the browser and server and the failed connection between python client and server and compare these, especially regarding offered ciphers, client certificates and protocol version. If you need help with  analysis you might upload the captures to cloudshark.org.

Comment: Look at No.2 UPDATE

Comment: The attempt in update.1 to use the servers certificate both as trusted CA certificate (`verify`) and as your own client certificate w/o having the private key (`cert`) makes no sense and results of course in the given error that no private key can be found. As for update.2: I assume that is an interception from the (working) browser and not the python script - but it makes no sense to capture HTTP traffic if the problem is at the TLS layer. Please do a packet capture of the TLS traffic for both browser and python code instead, using wireshark, tcpdump or similar.

Comment: FIXED, The problem was on the server side [ server certificate ]

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you need to create a SSL context, and pass it to requests.

```
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) #if you need TLS v1.2
```

and then, pass this context var to the requests method. If an optional keyword argument, name `context`. So, the call will be like this:

`resp = requests.get(addr, ...., context=context)`

Comment: again error with this content. " request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context' "